# Ionic Accessing video files downloaded to dataDirectory

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, videogular

I am using Ionic3 with videogular2.

App that i developed is a e-learning app that provides video tutorials to the users. It has feature to download videos so that user can use the app offline.
I used [fileTransfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) plugin to download files and [file](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) plugin to provide paths and checking files.

Files are getting downloaded correctly without any problems, the problem is after download i am unable to access the file through my app's player(videogular2) while in android it works fine without any problems.

tried different solutions but nothing worked.
**1.**[trial1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622979/html5-video-play-not-playing-ionic-3-ios-and-android?rq=1)  **2.**[trial2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/4668)  **3.**[trial3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455858/cordova-external-app-local-video).Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show your file transfer method code

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar here's the code `this.fileTransfer.download(cur_down["url"],this.file.dataDirectory+cur_down["name"]).then(
        (entry) =>{
         --my code--},
        (err) =>{

        }
      );`

Answer (score -1):

Try once `this.file.externalRootDirectory` instead of `this.file.dataDirectory`

For storage related details please visit here

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files

Comment: The issue is with iOS not android I think iOS didn't have external root directory